# maximum modulus principle implies Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Today during the qualifying exam I met this question:

Show that the maximum modulus principle implies the Liouville Theorem.

Well, this is my attempt:

It suffices to show that a bounded entire function can achieve its maximum modulus in complex plane. But I got messed up here. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: See also *Second proof of proposition 6.3*, pg. 58 of http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/complex.pdf

Comment: @Jacob Bond, Thank you very much! Can't believe I didn't think in that way... And, this proof also indicates that one cannot merely apply M.M.P to prove Liouville's Theorem. Riemann removable singularity theorem has to be used.

Comment: @Jacob Bond, I just realized it's you.. I'm Qinfeng. How did you feel about the exam yesterday?

Comment: @Jacob Bond, me too, I was hurt by the 1st problem, but felt good about the others. Well, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Show that the maximum modulus principle implies the Liouville Theorem.

The function

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{1+\lvert z\rvert}$$

which is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and the unit disk shows that the maximum modulus principle *alone* does not imply Liouville's theorem. We need some more properties of holomorphic functions.

> It suffices to show that a bounded entire function can achieve its maximum modulus in complex plane. But I got messed up here. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Something closely related: Riemann's removable singularity theorem.

The Riemann sphere is compact, so every continuous function on the entire sphere ...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Actually I thought about the Riemann sphere during the exam, and I also noticed that $\infty$ is a removable singularity. But what could be implied here? I'm sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: You get a holomorphic function defined on the entire sphere. In particular, that function is continuous.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that. I mean, a continuous function $f$ on a compact manifold can achieve its maximum modulus on the boundary. Riemann sphere has no boundary, and maximum modulus can be obtained on $\infty$ if no extra result is considered. So how to derive a contradiction?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for pointing out my mistake! Apologies for misleading the OP.

Comment: @user167839 $\lvert f\rvert$ must attain its maximum at some point on the sphere. If it attains the maximum at $\infty$ (and you don't know yet that it is constant), consider the function $g(z) = f(1/z)$.

Comment: So $g$ is entire and attained its maximum modulus at zero, which contradicts the M.M.P.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Schwarz Lemma will give you Liouville's theorem, and the Schwarz Lemma can be obtained from the maximum principle and the open mapping theorem.