# Analytic function with vanishing derivatives.

Tags: complex-analysis

A function that is analytic in the whole plane and which vanishes along with all its derivatives at any one point in the plane is identical to $0$. Now consider a function $f(z)$, which is supposedly analytic everywhere such that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f^{(n)}(z)=0$$ for $n=0, 1, 2...$ Is the conclusion that $f(z)$ is identical to $0$ the only possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$ already implies that $f \equiv 0$.

That follows from the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle),
or from [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: That's Liouville, not maximum principle.

Comment: Yes,  but the answer did remind me that $f$ would be bounded.

Comment: @zhw.: Thanks! My impression was that the maximum modulus principle implies Liouville, but after reading http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894304/maximum-modulus-principle-implies-liouvilles-theorem I understand that this is not completely correct.

Comment: @zhw.: But the conclusion $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0 \Longrightarrow f \equiv 0$ would also follow from the maximum principle, without using Liouville, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it would ...