# A question around Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers

Liouville's theorem of complex analysis states that a bounded entire function is constant. This means that for a non-constant entire function $f$ there exists a sequence $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_n| \to \infty$ and $f(z_n) \to \infty$. I am trying to understand if a sort of converse holds in the following sense: consider a closed set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ ($S$ may be unbounded) such that $\mathbb{C} \setminus S$ is unbounded. Can one construct a non-constant entire function $f$ such that $f$ is bounded on $S$ ?

Comment: Cross-posted on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253428/a-question-around-liouvilles-theorem).

Comment: Try the [Maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle). But see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894304/maximum-modulus-principle-implies-liouvilles-theorem.

Comment: What if $S= \{0\}?$

Comment: @lhf What if the maximum is attained at some boundary point of $S$?

Comment: Yes, for every curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(t) \to \infty$, there exists a function bounded everywhere except in the neighborhood of the curve, search for the [Alice Roth's theorems](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1652721/276986) on entire functions