# Liouville Theorem And Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Liouville Theorem states that: every bounded entire function must be constant.

Now if we know that the function is continuous on the boundary (can it be not continuous on the boundary?) what can we conclude?

(I know that there is something in regard to the max/min but do not fully understand)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Which boundary?

Comment: Are you confusing Liouville's Theorem with the [Maximum Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)? See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894304/maximum-modulus-principle-implies-liouvilles-theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer if we look on an entire and bounded function on $\overline{D}$

Comment: @gbox **Holomorphic** (on an open set $\Omega$) = it has the complex derivative at each point of $\Omega$. **Entire** = holomorphic on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @lhf yes, that what I was talking about, thanks!

Comment: $f(z) = e^z$ is holomorphic and bounded on $|z| \le 1$ and it is non-constant.  The liouville theorem is if $f(z)$ is holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, then it is constant.